# Necessary and sufficient condition for semi-direct product of a group G with a normal subgroup N and some subgroup H

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, semidirect-product

Let $G$ be a group and $N\triangleleft G$ be a normal subgroup. Then $G\cong N\rtimes H$ for some subgroup $H\leq G$ if and only if there exists a group homomorphism $\psi:G/N\rightarrow G~,~\psi(gN)\in gN$ for all $g\in G$.

My best attempt is as follows.

$(\Rightarrow)$: I am not very sure how to define the group homomorphism $\psi$ to obtain the desired result.

$(\Leftarrow)$: Suppose that we have a group homomorphism $\psi:G/N\rightarrow G~,~\psi(gN)\in gN$ for all $g\in G$. Let $H\leq G$ be the subgroup such that ${\rm ker}\left(\psi\right)=H/N\leq G/N$. Define $\phi:N\rtimes_{f} H\rightarrow G$ such that $(n,h)\mapsto nh$, where $f:H\rightarrow {\rm Aut}(N)~,~h\mapsto f(h)(n)=hnh^{-1}$. Then 
\begin{align*}
\phi\left(\left(n_{1},h_{1}\right)\left(n_{2},h_{2}\right)\right)&=\phi\left(n_{1}f(h_{1})(n_{2}),h_{1}h_{2}\right)
\\
&=n_{1}f(h_{1})(n_{2})h_{1}h_{2}
\\
&=n_{1}h_{1}n_{2}h_{2}
\\
&=\phi\left(n_{1},h_{1}\right)\psi\left(n_{2},h_{2}\right)
\end{align*}
so that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism. $\phi$ is 1-1 since if $(n,h)\in{\rm ker}(\phi)$, then $nh=\phi(n,h)=1_{G}$ which gives $n=h^{-1}$. Note that $H$ is a subgroup containing $N$ and so $N\cap H=N$. Thus, $\psi(h^{-1}N)\in N$ and so $n_{0}=\psi(h^{-1}N)$ for some $n_{0}\in N$.

I would appreciate any hints, preferably without the use of exact sequences. Thank you.

Comment: For $\Rightarrow$, note that $G/N\cong H$. What you do for the converse is just plain wrong. Note that $\psi$ is one-to-one: if $gN\in\mathrm{ker}(\psi)$, then $\psi(gN)=e$. But since $\psi(gN)\in gN$, that means that $e\in gN$ hence $g\in N$, and $gN$ is the identity of $G/N$. So your $H$ is just $N$ itself, and you are trying to define an isomorphism from $N\rtimes N$ to $G$. That's not going to work.

Comment: $n=h^{-1}$ does not tell you your $\phi$ is one-to-one. In fact, it tells you otherwise, since then the element $(n,n^{-1})$ will lie in the kernel, and if $n\neq e$, then it is not trivial. Thus, your $\phi$ is not one-to-one. Because you picked your $H$ to **contain** $N$, whereas in a semidirect product you need $H$ and $N$ to intersect trivially. that should also have been a warning sign.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin sorry I am not sure which direction you are pointing me in for the hint you gave for $\Rightarrow$. Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin I see my error now for $\Leftarrow$. On that note, I am wondering if $H$ should be a subgroup of $G/N$ instead of subgroup of $G$. Do you have any suggestions with regard to this?

Comment: No, $H$ should be a subgroup of $G$; you want to show that $G=N\rtimes H$, after all. As to $\Rightarrow$, $G/N=HN/N\cong H/N\cap H = H/\{e\}$, so there should be an obvious way of mapping $G/N$ back into $H$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thanks. I managed to solve it and also with $H={\rm Im}(\psi)$.